# stuck with master method

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

$$T (n) = 3T (n/5) + \log^2 n$$

i am trying to solve this recurrence i have been told that it is master methods case 1 but how do i compare $\log^2n$ with $n^ {\log_5 3}$

Comment: i mean how can i decide weather $log^2n$ = $O(n^{log_5 3})$ or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rule of thumb is that polynomial functions always grow faster than logarithmic functions.  E.g. [this lecture](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mihalis/cs4231/Handouts/Asymptotics.pdf). So your polynomial function asymptotically dominates your log function, giving you case 1.

If you want to know why powers grow faster than logs, you can put the functions in a ratio and then evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$.

Comment: polynomials grow faster than logs agreed, but in this case it's the square of the log function how to go about that ?

Comment: am i doing something incorrect here ?

Comment: Polys grow faster than logs, no matter what power you raise the logs to.  You can take the limit of the ratio to prove this, or look at Trevor's answer below where he works through the math.

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit: Consider $n=e^x$ and the fact that $e^{\varepsilon x}$ grows faster than $x^m$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ (small as you wish) and $m>0$ (large as you wish).

Comment: @dsolimano Thanks a lot for your comment it helped a lot.

Comment: @shai covo thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

This comment below makes explicit what the first answer already said, and hopefully removes the confusion regarding polylogs that seems to persist in the OP's mind.

To see why, consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^k}{n^\epsilon}$$ for any positive $\epsilon$ and any positive integer $k$ (integrality is not really necessary, but suffices for our purposes).

We have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^k}{n^\epsilon} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \underbrace{\frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon/k}}\cdots \frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon/k}}}_{k-\mathrm{times}}.$$

Thus, it all boils down to proving that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^\gamma} = 0,$$
where $\gamma > 0$, and we already know how to prove this.

So, I hope this provides the clarification the OP sought.

Answer (score 2):

So we want to show that $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_{b}a})$ and $f(n) = O(n^{\log_{b}(a)-\epsilon})$. So $a=3, b=5, f(n) = \log^{2} n$, and $\log_{5} 3 = 0.6826$. So we check the following:

- $f(n) = \log^{2} n = O(n^{0.6826- \epsilon})$. So choose any $\epsilon >0$. In other words, $\log^{2} n \in o(n^{0.6826- \epsilon})$. Note the derivative of $(\log n)^2 = \frac{2 \log n}{n}$ and the derivative of $n^{0.6826}$ is $\frac{0.6826}{n^{0.3174}}$.

The result follows.

Comment: but this is what my question was how do we arrive at the result that $n^{0.6826- \epsilon}$ asymptotically larger than  $\log^{2} n$

Answer (score 1):

There  is another  closely  related recurrence  that  admits an  exact
solution. Suppose we have $T(0)=0$ and $T(1)=T(2)=T(3)=T(4)=1$ and for
$n\ge 5$
$$T(n) = 3 T(\lfloor n/5 \rfloor) + \lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor^2.$$

Then we  can unroll the  recurrence to obtain the  following **exact**
formula for $n\ge 5$
$$T(n) = 3^{\lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor -1} 
3^j \times (\lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor - j)^2.$$
Note that this is independent of the actual digits of $n.$

This simplifies to
$$\frac{5}{2} 3^{\lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor}
- \frac{1}{2} \lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor^2
- \frac{3}{2} \lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor
- \frac{3}{2}.$$

Now the  first term is  obviously the dominant one  asymptotically, so
that we get the following answer for the complexity of the recurrence:

$$T(n)\in\Theta\left(3^{\lfloor \log_5 n \rfloor}\right)
= \Theta\left(3^{\log_5 n}\right)
= \Theta\left(5^{\log_5 3 \times \log_5 n}\right)
= \Theta\left(n^{\log_5 3}\right).$$

This agrees with what the Master Theorem would say.

This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595904/can-master-theorem-be-applied-on-any-of-these) has a series of similar calculations.