# Master theorem, algorithms $T(n) = 2T(n/3) + \log n$

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Can I solve
 $ T(n) = 2T(n/3) + \log n $ using the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)?
It doesn't seem to fit in any case.

Comment: Let $F(n) = T(3^n)$, continue from there.  Careful about asymptotic assumptions when making exponential changes of variables though.  Whether $F(n) \in O(g(n))$ implies that $T(n) \in O(g(\log n))$ is something that should be considered carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this doesn't use the master theorem, but your problem screams for a logarithm.  I plugged in $T(n)=a\log n+b$ and got $a=-1$ and $b=-2\log 3$.  Natural logarithms, of course.

Answer (score 1):

We can give a solution to the following recurrence
$$T(n) = 2 T(\lfloor n/3 \rfloor) + \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor$$
for $n\ge 3$ where we set $T(1) = T(2) = 1.$

Now it is not difficult to see that for $n\ge 3$
we have the **exact** relation
$$T(n) = 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
2^j (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j )$$
which is independent of the ternary digits of $n.$

This simplifies to
$$3\times 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
- \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - 2.$$
The dominant term here is clearly $2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}$ so that

$$T(n)\in \Theta\left(2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}\right)
= \Theta(3^{\log_3 2 \times \log_3 n})
= \Theta(n^{\log_3 2}).$$

The Master theorem does apply here. This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595904/can-master-theorem-be-applied-on-any-of-these) presents several related computations.